# SELECT DISTINCT on one column or make duplicate entries _blank, while returning other columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query which returns about 10 columns.
Second column of the query output contains duplicate records, But if possible I need it to be distinct or make duplicate records blank of only second column.

my data looks something like that

```
HotelID  ChainID
1041     10
1099     9
1297     10
1743     9
2000     10
241      10
```

The required ouput should be

```
HotelID ChainID
1041    10
1099    9
1297    
1743    
2000    
241
```

I have

```
Select Distinct id, val1
FROM table1 where active=0
```

I also tried using `Group By` but same result.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The group by wouldn't black the values, but will group them, then it's up to you when reading the values to keep track so you can "blank" out the duplicates.

Comment: @GiladGreen: sql only. but if possible with C# then  I can try with C# also.

Comment: This looks strange. You want a result with two columns. You show associated hotels and chains. But why would you be interested in hotel 1041 belonging to chain 10 (and only because this hotel happens to be the first in the results), but not be interested in hotel 1297 for instance? To me it seems you don't want to see Relations at all, but two queries actually: one to give you distinct hotels, and one to give you distinct chains. Don't make this one query; it doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: yes you're correct. But according to the current requirement and if possible I need to do it in single query.

Comment: If you want both columns to have two distinct values, what you really want is to have two distinct queries and then combine result however you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run the below query to get the value it will full fill your need.

```
select hotelid,case when row_number()over(partition by ChainID order by HotelID)=1 then chainid else null end as ChainID  from table1 where active=0
```

out put

```
hotelid ChainID 
1099       9
1743      NULL
241        10
1041      NULL
1297      NULL
2000      NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! Get the exact Result :)

Comment: can you please explain the query and result?

Comment: This is Gordon's query compressed. Explanation: The records get numbered per ChainID, so there is always one record per ChainID with number 1, then maybe others with number 2, 3, and so on. With the case expression we only show the ChainID for the records that got number 1, so each ChainID is shown only once.

Comment: in the query we add a new row called row number.
for example for same chain-id we give row number 1,2,3, then in select we write condition like if row num is one take the chain-id else null so for all distinct chain-id there will be a one in row number that we will select for all others we put null.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.HotelId,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then ChainId end) as ChainId
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by chainId order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks but, It is returning all rows of ChainID as NULL , However I only wants to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @Rahul Hendawe: Add `order by seqnum` to see the chainids on top.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: I'm getting 10 rows so I can view the result clearly all column values are `NULL` . Sorry I forgot to add `WHERE` in SQL query please check `WHERE Active=0`.

Comment: The where clause must be added after `from t`, i.e. in the subquery (derived table), not in the main query after `) t`.

Answer (score 1):

This query doesn't seem to make much sense, as two columns represent a relation. Well, if you want to select all data in one query to save time somehow, you may want this instead:

```
select distinct 'chain' as what, chainid as id from mytable
union all
select distinct 'hotel' as what, hotelid as id from mytable
order by what, id;
```

Giving you:

```
what   id
-----  ----
chain  9
chain  10
hotel  241     
hotel  1041
hotel  1099
hotel  1297    
hotel  1743    
hotel  2000
```

Comment: Thanks this is working! but I need output in mention table format. Can you please change the query so that it will display output as mention in question?

Comment: I'd use the same technique as shown by Gordon Linoff then. My query wouldn't be different from his.